# CakePHP find is not returing all the fields when using a join

Tags: cakephp

Hi Im trying to join 2 tables Reports and ReportResults in my Report model

```
$report = $this->find('first', array(
                'joins' => array(
                    array(
                        'table'      => 'report_results',
                        'alias'      => 'rr',
                        'type'       => 'INNER',
                        'fields'     => array(
                            "Report.*", "rr.*"
                        ),
                        'conditions' => array(
                            "rr.report_id = {$this->alias}.id",
                            "{$this->alias}.status" => Report::STATUS_GENERATED,
                            "{$this->alias}.start_day = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY",
                        )
                    )
                ),

                'order' => array("rr.total DESC")
            ));
```

My problem is that only the Report tables fields are being returned. It doesnt appear to be taking the fields part into the query. Initially I didnt have the fields specified but  when I do specify them or try to limit the fields returned with only a few of the Report fields it still returns the entire set.

Can someone point out what I might be missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical! I spent ages looking around before I posted the question and I soon as I  posted it I found the answer.

So by moving the fields out of the join it works

```
$report = $this->find('first', array(
                'joins' => array(
                    array(
                        'table'      => 'report_results',
                        'alias'      => 'rr',
                        'type'       => 'INNER',

                        'conditions' => array(
                            "rr.report_id = {$this->alias}.id",
                            "{$this->alias}.status" => Report::STATUS_GENERATED,
                            "{$this->alias}.start_day = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY",
                        )
                    )
                ),

                'fields'     => array(
                            "Report.*", "rr.*"
                        )

                'order' => array("rr.total DESC")
            ));
```